# How to add a custom block in the Magento dashboard sidebar

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to add some notification in admin panel dashboard in left sidebar, where by default 5 notification are shows. please see in this image I have marked.

[image]

Comment: You should add some examples of what you've tried that aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/dashboard

and open the `index.phtml` file.

[image: Look here]